# SO pages do not react to clicks (share/close/flag/comment links defunct)?

Tags: support

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315050/need-assistance-with-devising-algorithms#), and intended to write a comment. But alas, when I click the "comment" link ... nothing happens?! I then clicked the delete link: same thing. My browser just sits there, doing nothing. Then I turned to other questions on Stack Overflow ... same thing. I shutdown my browser ... same result. (I am using Google Chrome 70.0.3538.102 on macOS.)

Updates: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318172/nullpointer-at-lambda-expression#), following the advice from Erik, I get

[image: screenshot]

It turns out resources such as:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=91f6f91fc883
https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js
```

fail to load. I then switched to Firefox, and it is working fine.

So, obviously it is not a Stack Overflow problem, but something local with my browser on my machine. But still, it is annoying.

Comment: Can't repro. Works fine for me.

Comment: This is a bit of an odd way to handle a bug report. Jumping to the top of the page is the default behavior if the JavaScript responsible for handling comments hasn't fully loaded yet. Can you take other actions requiring JS (e.g. open the flagging dialog)?

Comment: The site has been unresponsive sometimes for me as well the past hour. Long loading times. Probably some maintenance work or network hiccups somewhere. The down- and closevoting on this question are weird.

Comment: Well, the edit link is a hard link and works without JS. Apparently, you're not properly loading the JavaScript required for SO to function properly. You can use the network pane on the debugging tools to see if resources are loading, and if not, usually it clarifies why not. Open it, and use Ctrl + F5 to do a hard refresh on a malfunctioning page. Then, you might be able to track it down to a specific resource not being found.

Comment: This looks like a problem getting the appropriate js assets on your end, not a bug in the platform. Same version of Chrome on a Mac, everything works.

Comment: Regarding your edit: check the network tab in the inspector, to see if any assets are failing to load or blocked. Specifically, JS files.

Comment: Are you behind a (work/education)proxy? Did you wipe your browser's cache? Did you try other browsers?

Comment: If you press `[Ctrl]`+`[Shift]`+`[Del]` in chrome, you can chose what to delete. _"Cached images and files"_ is what you want to delete. The other options should be unchecked.

Comment: Did that fix the problem? Then I'd suggest adding an answer, yourself, as it can be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Eh, good point. Then the status quo seems okay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users [Erik](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth), [yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi) and [Cerbrus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) helped tracking down the issue, and resolving it.

It turned out that some JavaScript-related resources weren't loading (at all) when a page was loaded. One can find that by turning to `Inspect` in the Chrome context menu. Then you just reload the page, and look into the Network tab. In case there are errors, they will show up there. Clearly a **local** browser issue, not a server-side issue.

The solution for me was pretty simple: turn to the "3 dots" side menu, then "more tools", then clear browsing data.

I selected "for last 24 hours", and used the "defaults" from the advanced selection page:

[image: Menu]

Afterwards: all fine!

**The one downside**: I lost my [auto messages](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments)!

Comment: FWIW, you're not alone... My boss' Chrome also does this with some of our own assets... Never found the real culprit though (I think it's been several Chrome's version now, and I never experienced it on mine), and unfortunately, clearing the cache is just a temporary solution, the bug may come back eventually...