# Uncaught ReferenceError: winterBashCurrentHats21477067 is not defined

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2018

I am not sure if we are supposed to report this here, but I was working with the Chrome Dev Tools open and I am getting, once in a while, an Uncaught Reference Error:

[image]

More detail:

[image: What appears to be JSON values for winterBashCurrentHats21477067.]

Can't see the stack.

[image: Call stack just says "anonymous".]

It is a bit hard to reproduce but I go to the [main page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and then randomly click one of the posts, sometimes I get the error, sometimes I don't (I do get it fairly frequently though).

I am using the Sun Wukong hat. (Also not sure if relevant but I have one tab open with a chat from SO).

Let me know if I can add more data.

Comment: I'm sure the SO devs can debug this just fine, but I'm curious: can this be reliably reproduced whenever you view particular questions? It's likely got nothing to do with your own hat, and everything to do with specific other hats.

Comment: @RToyo Well I tested more times, it looks like the very first time I enter to a page I get that error. I think I got it several times in some pages, but overall anytime I enter for the first time to a page I seem to be getting it.

Comment: That's actually a super secret hat...

Comment: I'm seeing this hard error as well in IE11. I want my hat. :)

Comment: `but I was working with the Chrome Dev Tools open` OMG, stop hacking the website! I need to go and post a question on how to disable the dev tools, so people don't hack MY site and steal all my powerful codes. /s

Comment: @vlaz There should be a huge stop sign printed in the console after opening Dev Tools. I have something like this on my banking website.

Comment: @Skipper That's because banks (and places for the great unwashed, like Facebook) are a target ripe for social engineering attacks, sometimes involving telling people to open Dev Tools and paste in a secret code (which turns out to be some obfuscated JS to trigger sending me all your money, or at least to try doing so). It would be pretty annoying on SO, particularly as we are all devs here _and_ there's no real attack surface here that I can detect.

Comment: I suspect this is a dupe of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376675/so-pages-do-not-react-to-clicks-share-close-flag-comment-links-defunct/376683#comment647655_376683 Could you check your devtools "Network" panel? That would be a chrome cache bug.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well ... some ppl can post answers even after questions are put on hold ... if that is an attack surface though ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner Funny you say that; I did it 10 minutes ago :D (I'd already written most of it when "it happened" and then cast a valid re-open vote!) But no I don't think that counts as what we're talking about

Comment: @Kaiido I checked the network tab, cleaning the resources actually stopped the problem for a little bit, but it started to happen again.  I don't see any resources failing to load in the network tab. And also David W pointed out it also happens on IE11.